# Trying to vertically align two columns in zurb foundation

Tags: html, css, sass, vertical-alignment, zurb-foundation

I'm using Zurb Foundation with Sass Compass, but this could a problem for anything in css.

So, I have code like this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-6 column">...</div>
    <div class="small-6 column">...</div>
</div>
```

The columns have content of differing height determined by how much text and images I want to put in there. The row has no explicit height and determined by the height of the tallest column. Now the tallest column will be shown as is, but the other one which is shorter, I'd like it's content to be centered vertically. I have looked around for this and I've tried using display: table and relative positioning, but none of them offers what I need.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the vertical aligned text in a div with the same height as its parent and display:table-cell it (after displaying its parent as a table):

HTML

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-6 column">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam et iaculis justo. Mauris bibendum convallis est, vel blandit quam tempor aliquet. Cras euismod nibh et nisl congue, eget tincidunt mauris consectetur. Donec eu risus lectus. Integer at ipsum sed turpis fringilla adipiscing vitae vel enim.</div>
        <div class="small-6 column"><div class="v_align">Some text</div></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
<div style="width:200px; height:100px; background:#0f0; color:#fff;">dfbvd bdfhgf hfg hghf gfdh hfgghfd hgf</div>
```

CSS

```
.row{
    width:300px;
    height:auto;    
}
.clear{clear:both;}

.column:first-child{
    color:#f00;
    background:#ccc;
}
.column:nth-child(2){
    background:#999;
    color:#00f;
    display:table;
}
.column{
    width:150px;
    float:left;
}
.v_align{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var rowHeight = $(".row").height();
    console.log(rowHeight);
    $(".column").height(rowHeight);
    $(".v_align").height(rowHeight);
});
```

Check the result: http://jsfiddle.net/gespinha/h6aPf/6/

Comment: Interesting solution, but unfortunately, I cannot give any height attribute to neither the row nor the columns. My first column contains dynamic text with one h2 tag and 0 to several p tags. My second column contains a img tag of a relatively large dimension. The image will scale and keep it's aspect ratio, so as I make the browser expands or contracts, the height is also going to change. I'm making a completely flexible layout. If pixels were determined in advance, I'd probably use relative positioning. Anyway, I'll leave this for tonight and if there is no solution, I'll use javascript.

Comment: I have updated the answer above with a new solution, is it what you needed?

Comment: This is a two fold response. First, when you use position: absolute on the row, if I put anything following div.row, I'd have it behind it which is not what I want. Second, when you put height to 100% for all three div, it takes the entire height of the page while I want it to only take as much height as needed by the content.

Comment: Updated the post above, you have to add some javascript for that. I used Jquery on the example above. the div stretches and determines the height as the content is inserted. I've added a new green div, to show you how it works great now :)

Comment: Thanks, I just finished up writing a script myself, but yours is more elegant using the row height. I was actually doing MAX(all column heights) and removing the style on each resize to apply it again. I'm giving you a vote up for this, but ultimately, it doesn't answer my question as I didn't want to get js involved. I'm still hoping someone will come up with a pure css solution.

Comment: Actually, if W3C is final on their roadmap, CSS4 will probably allow us to do what you want without javascript, once variables can be applied inside CSS. Nowadays, unfortunately you still can't compare or relate heights in CSS and without that capability, you couldn't do this. Thanks for the challenge ;)