# Vertical Alignment - Foundation 5 - Simple Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, zurb-foundation, vertical-alignment

I've used the technique explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18455038/trying-to-vertically-align-two-columns-in-zurb-foundation) [(js.fiddle link)](http://jsfiddle.net/gespinha/h6aPf/6/) to achieve vertical alignment for a section on my page.

The problem I have is that I would like to re-use this same technique on a different part of my page.

At the moment this works, but obviously the height of the first instance is then applied to a completely unrelated section somewhere else, and the vertical alignment is not achieved. Could someone help me with modifying the js (maybe using 'this'?) to allow the use of the same code to apply the height to different elements in different parts of my page?

Or do I have to duplicate this code with different var/class names each time I want to use it?

Code snippets below

HTML

```
<div class="row row_v_align">
  <div class="small-3 columns column_v_align">
    <div class="v_align"><img src="spade.png"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="small-9 columns">
    <h3>Title</h3><p>Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row row_v_align">
  <div class="small-3 columns column_v_align">
    <div class="v_align"><img src="bullsEye.png"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="small-9 columns">
    <h3>Title</h3><p>Content.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.row_v_align {
  display: table;
}
.v_align {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

JS

```
$(window).on("resize", function () {
  var rowHeight = $(".row_v_align").height();
  console.log(rowHeight);
  $(".column_v_align").height(rowHeight);
  $(".v_align").height(rowHeight);
}).resize();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested code below with fiddle you linked.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".row").each(function(){
        var rowHeight = $(this).height();
        console.log(rowHeight);
        $(".column", this).height(rowHeight);
        $(".v_align", this).height(rowHeight);
    });
});
```

So for you this should work:

```
$(window).on("resize", function () {
  $(".row_v_align").each(function(){
    var rowHeight = $(this).height();
    console.log(rowHeight);
    $(".column_v_align", this).height(rowHeight);
    $(".v_align", this).height(rowHeight);
  });
}).resize();
```

- each() run function for every matched element
- $("...", this) makes sure that changes are made inside current row

Comment: Thank you zola. This is exactly what I was after.